# Bootstrap 4 & Codeignitier 4 - Larger screen view and smaller screen view and how to handle forms

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-4

I would like to have two different menus for larger screens and smaller screens.  I am easily able to accomplish with the below code.  My question is how to place the form code?  If I have 2 forms of the same name that seems like a problem.  How does one handle this? I have a profile form, profile-image form, password form and timezone form.  If I duplicate the form on the same page for large and small screens, seems I am asking for trouble.  How to handle this pls?

```
<!--
https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/bootstrap/bootstrap-hide-element-based-on- 
viewport-size/
-->

<!-- begin larger screen sizes here -->
<div class="d-none d-md-block">[insert menu for large screen size]</div>

<!-- begin small screens -->
<div class="d-block d-md-none">

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <!-- profile -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile"><i class="fas fa-id-card"></i></a>
    </li>
    <!-- profile image -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile-image"><i class="fas fa-images"></i></a>
    </li>
    <!-- password -->
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#password"><i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i></a>
    </li>
    <!-- timezone --> 
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#timezone"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
      
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane container active" id="profile">[insert profile settings form here]</div>
    <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="profile-image">[insert profile-image settings form here]</div>
    <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="password">[insert profile password form here]</div>
    <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="timezone">[insert profile timezone form here]</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you thinking of having 2 forms? If it's responsiveness, can't you handle the different viewports using bootstrap using something like this?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1>Responsive Form</h1>
      <h2>Send us a message</h2>
      <form action="/sendFrm" method="post" id="contactFrm">
        <div>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="contactName" placeholder="Your name" aria-label="your name" required>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="contactEmail" placeholder="Your email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
          <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="contactMessage" rows="5" placeholder="Your message" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn inline-block">Send</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also don't forget to include your csrf_field() if it is a form post.

If it's for another reason, please let me know why.

Thanks

Comment: Please re-look my html.  I have tabs on big screens and pills on small screens.  I do not see a way to use the same form other than using the same form twice.  If you know how to do this, please advise.  Thanks.